# Convert DATE From Sysdate Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, converters, sysdate

Now I need select Sysdate from DB . I using Hibernate : 
This is my code

```
Session session = null;
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateConnnection.createSessionFactory();
     session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    String hqlSelect = "select to_char(sysdate, 'dd/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AS GIO FROM DUAL";
     session.beginTransaction();
     SQLQuery query1 = session.createSQLQuery(hqlSelect);
     DateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
     Date dutyDay = (Date) simpleDateFormat.parse(query1.uniqueResult().toString());
     return dutyDay;
```

When I select it, before I Parse to Format . It correct, But after I format follow :

```
DateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
Date dutyDay = (Date) simpleDateFormat.parse(query1.uniqueResult().toString());
```

It not correct.

Where I wrong and How to fix this. 
Thanks

Comment: do some simple debugging and print out the value of `query1.uniqueResult().toString()`